# Parsing Json string Help required

Tags: android, json

```
{"sessid":"Vn1qRrhZWUQxaF4Vq3AS-TSaCHnDwgJa8dYtI7ER_Xs",
"session_name":"SESS7b83e2fe2bcfd6997077715ad8799a43",
"user_product":[{"id":"19","uid":"1","created":"1336803149","modified":"1336803149",
"subject":"Patras Bukhari",]}}
```

> Blockquote  i have this json in a sting and i want to fetch data from the arrayy user_product
>   i have tried alot but unable to do that . And my project is on Android.
>   help is  appreciated in advance thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check following code

```
 String a = {"sessid":"Vn1qRrhZWUQxaF4Vq3AS-TSaCHnDwgJa8dYtI7ER_Xs",
 "session_name":"SESS7b83e2fe2bcfd6997077715ad8799a43",
 "user_product":[{"id":"19","uid":"1","created":"1336803149","modified":"1336803149",
 "subject":"Patras Bukhari",]}}

 JSONObject json1 = new JSONObject(a);
 JSONArray userProduct = json1.getJSONArray("user_product");
 for(int i = 0; i < userProduct.length();i++){
   JSONObject tempJSON = userProduct..getJSONObject(i);
   String id = tempJSON.getString("id");
   String uid = tempJSON.getString("uid");
   String created = tempJSON.getString("created");
   String modified = tempJSON.getString("modified");
   String subject = tempJSON.getString("subject");
 }
```

Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: bro i got 
{"uid":"1","link_download":"\/sites\/default\/files\/product_download\/monti.zip","buy":0,"status":"1","subject":"MontiCristo","image":"\/sites\/default\/files\/product_images\/count-of-monte-cristo-icon.png","authorname":"sami","type":"Book","version":"1","modified":"1336803339","id":"21","inappitem":"1","price":"0.99","imagepath":"public:\/\/product_images\/count-of-monte-cristo-icon.png","created":"1336803339","authorid":"5","categoryname":"Entertainment","catid":"3","note"}
using ur code 1 more anser to accept ur question how can i further pick Uid   user_product

Comment: hi shoaib, debug this code and check what are you getting in each iteration of for loop

Answer (score 1):

Is the above JSON the real one you are using? If it was, the format is not valid. I guess you might encounter some exceptions working with it. Regardless to the validity, you can get user_product array by

```
JSONObject source = new JSONObject(your_source);
JSONArray userProducts = source.getJSONArray("user_product");
for(int i = 0; i < userProducts.length(); i++){
  JSONObject product = userProducts.getJSONObject(i);
  int uid = product.getInt("uid"); //get the uid as integer
}
```

Comment: sorry i have na option to accept only 1 question  i m rating urs

Comment: bro i also want the value of session id from the same json object how to ?

Comment: as "session_id" is defined in the outmost element, referring to the code I posted above, you can access it by: String sessionId = source.getString("session_id");

Comment: sessionId= (String) json1.opt("sessid"); this helped me catch that ;)_ thnx

Comment: wha! sorry, i didn't write the right key in my last comment (session_id=>sessid). it's a relief you got it works. ; )